# Authenticating a particular user to a particular client using IdentityServer

Tags: c#, authentication, identityserver3, owin-middleware

I am using `IdentityServerV3` for authenticating users for few clients. I am having problems configuring `IdentityServer` in such a way that a specific `user` must be able to login to a specific `client.

Let's take the below scenario :

I have 2 clients  ->  `client1`, `client2`.
I have 3 users     ->  `user1`, `user2`, `user3`.

`user1` & `user2` have access to `client1` only. Whereas `user3` has access to `client2` alone.

When i try to login to `client1` with `user3` identity server is authenticating successfully. Which i don't want.

```
public static class Clients
{
    public static IEnumerable<Client> Get()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new Client 
            {
                Enabled = true,
                ClientName = "MVC Client",
                ClientId = "mvc",
                Flow = Flows.Hybrid,

                RedirectUris = new List<string>
                {
                    "https://localhost:44319/"
                }
            },
            new Client 
            {
                Enabled = true,
                ClientName = "MVC Client 2",
                ClientId = "mvc2",
                Flow = Flows.Hybrid,

                RedirectUris = new List<string>
                {
                    "https://localhost:44319/"
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Users are :

```
public static class Users
{
    public static List<InMemoryUser> Get()
    {
        return new List<InMemoryUser>
        {
            new InMemoryUser
            {
                Username = "bob",
                Password = "secret",
                Subject = "1",

                Claims = new[]
                {
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName, "Bob"),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.FamilyName, "Smith")
                }
            },
            new InMemoryUser
            {
                Username = "rob",
                Password = "secret",
                Subject = "2",

                Claims = new[]
                {
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName, "Rob"),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.FamilyName, "Thompson")
                }
            },
            new InMemoryUser
            {
                Username = "Jerry",
                Password = "secret",
                Subject = "3",

                Claims = new[]
                {
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName, "Jerry"),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.FamilyName, "Smith")
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Now  OWIN Startup class is :

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp =>
            {
                idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
                {
                    SiteName = "Embedded IdentityServer",
                    SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),

                    Factory = InMemoryFactory.Create(
                        users  : Users.Get(),
                        clients: Clients.Get(),
                        scopes : StandardScopes.All)
                });
            });
    }

    X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate()
    {
        return new X509Certificate2(
            string.Format(@"{0}\bin\identityServer\idsrv3test.pfx", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory), "idsrv3test");
    }
}
```

I don't see how `IdentityServer` knows which user bleongs to which client.  Is my scenario not supported by `IdentityServer` or am i missing anything.

**UPDATE**

```
    public class LocalRegistrationUserService : UserServiceBase
    {
        public class CustomUser
        {
            public string Subject { get; set; }
            public string Username { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
            public List<Claim> Claims { get; set; }
        }

        public static List<CustomUser> Users = new List<CustomUser>();

        public string ClientId { get; set; }

        public override Task AuthenticateLocalAsync(LocalAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            var user = Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username == context.UserName && x.Password == context.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult(user.Subject, user.Username);
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
}
```

`While registering the user i am redirecting him to a controller in Identity Server Host`.

```
 public class LocalRegistrationController : Controller
    {
        [Route("core/localregistration")]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(string signin)
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Route("core/localregistration")]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string signin, LocalRegistrationModel model)
        {
            var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new LocalRegistrationUserService.CustomUser
                {
                    Username = model.Username, 
                    Password = model.Password, 
                    Subject = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    Claims = new List<Claim>()
                };
                LocalRegistrationUserService.Users.Add(user);
                user.Claims.Add(new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName, model.First));
                user.Claims.Add(new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.FamilyName, model.Last));

                return Redirect("~/core/" + Constants.RoutePaths.Login + "?signin=" + signin);
            }

            return View();
        }
    }
```

**startup.cs**

```
 app.Map("/core", coreApp =>
            {
                var factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
                    .UseInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
                    .UseInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get());

                // different examples of custom user services
                //var userService = new RegisterFirstExternalRegistrationUserService();
                //var userService = new ExternalRegistrationUserService();

                var userService = new LocalRegistrationUserService();

                // note: for the sample this registration is a singletone (not what you want in production probably)
                factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(resolver => userService);
                factory.ViewService = new Registration<IViewService, CustomViewService>();
                var options = new IdentityServerOptions
                {
                    SiteName = "Identity Server 3",

                    SigningCertificate = Certificate.Get(),
                    Factory = factory,

                    AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions
                    {
                        IdentityProviders = ConfigureAdditionalIdentityProviders,
                        LoginPageLinks = new LoginPageLink[] { 
                            new LoginPageLink{
                                Text = "Register",
                               // Href = "~/externalregistration",
                                Href = "~/localregistration",
                                //Href = "localregistration"
                            },
                             new LoginPageLink{
                                Text = "Forgot Password?",
                                Href = "~/forgotpassword",
                                //Href = "localregistration"
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    EventsOptions = new EventsOptions
                    {
                        RaiseSuccessEvents = true,
                        RaiseErrorEvents = true,
                        RaiseFailureEvents = true,
                        RaiseInformationEvents = true
                    }
                };

                coreApp.UseIdentityServer(options);
            });
```

I need to understand the best way to  map a `user` to `client` while registering and make sure that user can only login to that client and not any other clients even though the `username` and `password` are same for all the clients for that user.

Comment: Did you resolve this? Can you share your solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you provide a custom claim to go in your id_token, named `application_access` with a value of an application/client the user has access to; which of there could be many. You could add this custom claim in your `IUserService` implementation and map this the same way you map other user specific claims.

Then, in your client, do a check for that specific claim and check if the logged in user has a claim with a specific value for that specific client.

https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45/blob/master/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/Authorization/WebApi/ScopeAttribute.cs

(mark: `RequireScope` is for access tokens and APIs, but you get the general idea)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i didn't quite understood it.  While registering a user through an additional link `Register` i need to map the user to that `client` from where the user redirected to `login` form  and that user should only be authenticated for that particular client.

Comment: I updated my question to give you better picture what i am trying to do. Hope it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Then just create a dynamic registerpage that takes a querystring param `application` and link to it from each app with each